# Option ID is shown instead of option value

Tags: option

As a German Shop we need to echo delivery time into the top of the productpage and the product grid. Normaly it does what it should, but in our latest installation it shows the option id instead of its value. ...same version 1.7.0.

[image: How it looks]

This is the code:

```
echo $this->getProduct()->getDeliveryTime();
```

This is not working, too:

```
$_product_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
echo $_product_helper->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $this->getProduct()->getDeliveryTime(), 'delivery_time');
```

Even no other option value is shown there, no matter which attribute I try to echo. It just shows the correct option id. In other sections, e.g. under Additional Information it shows the right value.

Why does the same code do different things? 
And what could be the cause for that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't. If I uninstall the extension, it is still the same... just mentioned that, cause this is important for German shops. 
To be more precise: In the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Tabs

Comment: ... it shows the value, but nearly everywhere else it returns the ids.

Comment: In addition I can't echo any option value of an attribute outside of the tabs section. That has nothing to do with the extension, but with the behavior of the mentioned LOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing that with `echo $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('delivery_time');`